How can I connect two Bose Wave Radio/CD players to one laptop?
I have two Bose Wave Radio / CD players in good working condition.
Instead of buying speakers for my laptop, how can I hook them both to laptop, like pic below?
I placed one player to the left of my laptop, and the other to the right. I want one player to work as the "left speaker," and the other player to work as the "right speaker."
please make this picture show up - https://i.imgur.com/SkidBBd.jpeg

You can't. You may connect one using a simple 3.5mm stereo to 2 RCAs cable or adapter, that's it. And the device is stereo, what you want to do makes no sense.

You can get sound with something like what has been suggested.  However, it seems that you want to split the stereo channels from the laptop's output left and right?  If so, you won't be able to without a device in between your laptop and the Bose devices that will provide at least regular panning or, even better, split stereo panning.  Even then I'd question the viability of the sound produced...

The easiest thing to do would be to use each Bose unit as a stereo speaker (because each has two speakers), with a simple 3.5 mm to RCA cable (connected on one end to your laptop's headphone jack and on the other to the Bose unit's AUX IN).
What you can do however to achieve your desired result is to plug both sides of each of the Bose units to either side of your computers' output, using an RCA splitter.
Laptop -> 3.5 mm to RCA cable -> each side to an RCA splitter -> Thw two left outputs to the left device, the two right outputs to the right device.
